# getting args from a class returns 0 args

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I have the following class.

```
class myClass(tf.keras.Model):
   def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable, **kwargs):
      args = [inputs, outputs, name, trainable]
      super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I did this because I want my class to be similar to Functional class.
but when I execute the code and I debug it, it enters to the tf code (the Model class) and in **new** I can see that my kwargs has been passed but the args is 0.

I initialize my class like so:

```
model = myClass(inputs = model_inputs, outputs = model_outputs, name = model_name, **model_kwargs,)
```

my model_kwargs is a dict. In the debugger I can see my kwargs and it is not 0 but args are 0.

can someone help with his?

Comment: If that's all your `__init__` is doing, not defining it at all would have the same effect.

Comment: I do not have to define my `__init__`?

Comment: If you don't define a method it will use implementation from parent class, `tf.keras.Model` in this case.

Comment: yes but I do not understand what should I do in this case?

Comment: Providing some more code would certainly be helpful for answering your question.

Comment: I just want to know if I do this
`def __inti__(*args, **kwargs):`
and then create an object from myClass like so:
`model = myClass(inputs = model_inputs, outputs = model_outputs, name = model_name, **model_kwargs,)`

will *args be inputs, outputs, name, trainable?
it seems no in my case, I want to know if there is other thing to do to get what I am looking for? or am I missing something?

Comment: No, `inputs = model_inputs` etc. provides a *keyword* argument, therefore they will be in kwargs. If you want args, you can't use keywords (`input = `).